# Rails: how to make url with multi slash in Grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape

I'm using grape for restful service. As I know, `:resource` will define a path in url. For example:

```
module Sample
  module V1
    module Order
      class GetCheckInListApi < ApplicationApi
        resource :check_in_list do
          get root: :data do
             # business code here
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The url for example, will be: `localhost:8000/api/v1/check_in_list`. I want the url should be: `localhost:8000/api/v1/check_in/list`. How can I do in `Grape` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the resource has to be a `:check_in_list`? You could change it to `:chect_in` and add a `/list` route:

```
class GetCheckInListApi < ApplicationApi
  resource :check_in do
    get '/list' do
       # business code here
    end
  end
end
```